# Collaborating on Visual Studio project with non-Resharper user

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

If I have resharper installed on my computer and I collaborate on a visual studio project with another developer who does not have resharper will resharper make changes to the project that would prevent the other non-Resharper user from working on the project?

Comment: It'll be fine. Your differential productivity rates might make the other user sad though.

Comment: lol. Thanks for the input.  We had someone state that Resharper would actually change project files making it not work for others without Resharper.  There's nothing I've read that states it does that and JetBrains support also said it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Resharper doesn't modify the project files to the level of affecting the code itself and making it not functional.

I had resharper installed for a while, and then deleted it, and my projects remained working the same as they were just like before I install it.